# Multipane (smartphone/tablet) activity with fragment for List / Detail

Tags: android, android-fragments

What is the best approach to create a multipane list/detail activity for smartphone and tablet ?

The one I use currently is the one proposed by Android Studio, which does not maintain the state of the selected item on a change of orientation. 
There is one problematic case : when in portrait on the detail (so with the list activity behind), and after an orientation change, I want only the List activity to be restored displaying both the list fragment and the detail fragment. 
With the restore mecanism, both activites will be recreated,

**the problem is** : how to prevent the detail activity to be recreated as it is useless ? Is there any clean and simple way to do this ? (I don't want to eg finish the detail activity in its onCreate method)

One solution to this could be to use a different approach from AS but I can't find a satisfying one.
It can be to use only one activity, but in portrait I want to keep the 1 screen = 1 activity spirit (having a clear distinction between the list and the detail screen, eg having the screen fully refreshed (not just under the action bar) when passing from one to the other). Using 2 times this same activity leads to the same problem than with the AS solution. There is also the possibility to use the ToolBar widget on both fragments but it would add a little overload to the xml code, it should be possible using the default action bar.

Do you see a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finnaly resolved my problem using the following code in the detail activity :

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    if (isChangingConfigurations()){
        finish();
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```